# please fix this excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following formula that uses Named Ranges:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(BuildingNameLeases,A22,
     Lease_Move_In_Date,"<"&$T$1,
     vacated_date,{""","<"&$T$1-2"}))
```

It is not working and I don't know how to fix it.

It should be finding count of all building names **[BuildingNameLeases]** that match A22 where the move in date is before the date in T1 and the vacated date **[vacated_date]** is blank or 2 days before T1

Comment: it would be helpful if you post some of your data and tables and what error do you get?

Comment: post & ghost...

Answer (score 0):

Your last parameter is the problem. Arrays must be either ranges such as A1:B7 or absolutes such as `{4,"hello",7,"world"}`. They cannot contain cell references such as `{T1,L7}`.

To apply the logic you stated, you could do:

```
=SUM( (BuildingNameLeases=A22) * (Lease_Move_In_Date < $T$1) * (ISBLANK(vacated_date) + vacated_date < $T$1-2) )
```